# spring security 4.0 sql server express 2014 jdbc login issue

Tags: sql-server, spring-mvc, jdbc, authentication, spring-security

In my security context xml, I can see a warning, 'referenced bean dataSource not found', which if i ignore and try to login, getting the following error in eclipse console.

```
SEVERE: An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select username, password from users where username=?]; The index 3 is out of range.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 3 is out of range.
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
```

Below shown is security-context.xml, which has all the spring security bean mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select * from dbo.users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority from dbo.authorities where username=?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/createoffer"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/doCreate"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/offercreated"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/statc/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/offers"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error?true" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true" />
    </security:http>

</beans>
```

I tried with query `select * from dbo.users where username=?` as well as `select username, password from dbo.users where username=?`

While going through a spring security tutorial what I understood was, there's no need to specify a query at all, because spring fires a default query during authentication, we only need to create tables in the names `users` and `authorities`. So I tried that also. Nothing works.

dataSource is defined in another bean config file as below,

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/SpringTut" id="dataSource"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    </jee:jndi-lookup>
```

Not able identify what's wrong here. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is expected to return three columns: username, password and enabled. Your table only seems to have a username and password column.

You either need to add an enabled column, or you need to provide your own implementation of the `UserDetailsService`.

See the Spring Security reference [chapter 37 Security Schema](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-schema):

> The standard JDBC implementation of the UserDetailsService
>   (JdbcDaoImpl) requires tables to load the password, account status
>   (enabled or disabled) and a list of authorities (roles) for the user.
>   You will need to adjust this schema to match the database dialect you
>   are using.
>
> ```
> create table users(
>   username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
>   password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
>   enabled boolean not null
> );
> ```

And also see the code of [JdbcDaoImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java#JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername%28java.lang.String%29):

```
protected List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(usersByUsernameQuery, new String[] { username },
            new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
                public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                        throws SQLException {
                    String username = rs.getString(1);
                    String password = rs.getString(2);
                    boolean enabled = rs.getBoolean(3);
                    return new User(username, password, enabled, true, true, true,
                            AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
                }

            });
}
```

Comment: Ya when I added enabled in query it worked. Thank you for your response. :-)